# problem in the rest api flutter by package http

Tags: flutter, http, get, rest, data-class

I want to use package http but we do not get the output of our model. I have numbered each step by a print and I realized that the step number 1-1-1 does not go further and with the Chrome browser gives the error that is in the image.

error for build Google Chrome

[image]

service API class

```
    import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:test1/ModelTest.dart';

class ServiseApi {
  final httpcline = http.Client();
  Future<ModelUser> Login_Servise_Api() async {
    final keymodel = {'key': 'login', 'codeMEli': '1234567890', 'pass': '12345678'};

    final url = Uri.http('localhost', 'users.php', keymodel);
    print(url);
    final response = await http.get(url);

    print("ssssss" + response.toString());

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final responcJson = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print('number1');
      print(responcJson.toString());
      print('number1-1');

     final  modelUser =await  ModelUser.fromJson(responcJson);
      print('number2');
      print(modelUser.toString());
      print('number3');
      return modelUser;
    } else {
      return ModelUser(
          id: 'e',
          codeOffice: '0',
          codemeli: '0',
          password: '0',
          fname: '0',
          lname: '0',
          expdate: '0',
          tel: '0',
          mobile: '0',
          city: '0',
          address: '0',
          date: '0',
          pish: '0',
          edare: '0',
          flag: '0',
          type: '0',
          img: '0');
    }
  }
}
```

model class(data class)

```
import 'dart:convert';

class ModelUser {
  final String id;
  final String codeOffice;
  final String codemeli;
  final String password;
  final String fname;
  final String lname;
  final String expdate;
  final String tel;
  final String mobile;
  final String city;
  final String address;
  final String date;
  final String pish;
  final String edare;
  final String flag;
  final String type;
  final String img;
  ModelUser({
    required this.id,
    required this.codeOffice,
    required this.codemeli,
    required this.password,
    required this.fname,
    required this.lname,
    required this.expdate,
    required this.tel,
    required this.mobile,
    required this.city,
    required this.address,
    required this.date,
    required this.pish,
    required this.edare,
    required this.flag,
    required this.type,
    required this.img,
  });

  ModelUser copyWith({
    String? id,
    String? codeOffice,
    String? codemeli,
    String? password,
    String? fname,
    String? lname,
    String? expdate,
    String? tel,
    String? mobile,
    String? city,
    String? address,
    String? date,
    String? pish,
    String? edare,
    String? flag,
    String? type,
    String? img,
  }) {
    return ModelUser(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      codeOffice: codeOffice ?? this.codeOffice,
      codemeli: codemeli ?? this.codemeli,
      password: password ?? this.password,
      fname: fname ?? this.fname,
      lname: lname ?? this.lname,
      expdate: expdate ?? this.expdate,
      tel: tel ?? this.tel,
      mobile: mobile ?? this.mobile,
      city: city ?? this.city,
      address: address ?? this.address,
      date: date ?? this.date,
      pish: pish ?? this.pish,
      edare: edare ?? this.edare,
      flag: flag ?? this.flag,
      type: type ?? this.type,
      img: img ?? this.img,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'codeOffice': codeOffice,
      'codemeli': codemeli,
      'password': password,
      'fname': fname,
      'lname': lname,
      'expdate': expdate,
      'tel': tel,
      'mobile': mobile,
      'city': city,
      'address': address,
      'date': date,
      'pish': pish,
      'edare': edare,
      'flag': flag,
      'type': type,
      'img': img,
    };
  }

  factory ModelUser.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ModelUser(
      id: map['id'],
      codeOffice: map['codeOffice'],
      codemeli: map['codemeli'],
      password: map['password'],
      fname: map['fname'],
      lname: map['lname'],
      expdate: map['expdate'],
      tel: map['tel'],
      mobile: map['mobile'],
      city: map['city'],
      address: map['address'],
      date: map['date'],
      pish: map['pish'],
      edare: map['edare'],
      flag: map['flag'],
      type: map['type'],
      img: map['img'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory ModelUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return ModelUser(
      id: map['id'],
      codeOffice: map['codeOffice'],
      codemeli: map['codemeli'],
      password: map['password'],
      fname: map['fname'],
      lname: map['lname'],
      expdate: map['expdate'],
      tel: map['tel'],
      mobile: map['mobile'],
      city: map['city'],
      address: map['address'],
      date: map['date'],
      pish: map['pish'],
      edare: map['edare'],
      flag: map['flag'],
      type: map['type'],
      img: map['img'],
    );
  }
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'ModelUser(id: $id, codeOffice: $codeOffice, codemeli: $codemeli, password: $password, fname: $fname, lname: $lname, expdate: $expdate, tel: $tel, mobile: $mobile, city: $city, address: $address, date: $date, pish: $pish, edare: $edare, flag: $flag, type: $type, img: $img)';
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    return other is ModelUser &&
        other.id == id &&
        other.codeOffice == codeOffice &&
        other.codemeli == codemeli &&
        other.password == password &&
        other.fname == fname &&
        other.lname == lname &&
        other.expdate == expdate &&
        other.tel == tel &&
        other.mobile == mobile &&
        other.city == city &&
        other.address == address &&
        other.date == date &&
        other.pish == pish &&
        other.edare == edare &&
        other.flag == flag &&
        other.type == type &&
        other.img == img;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode {
    return id.hashCode ^
        codeOffice.hashCode ^
        codemeli.hashCode ^
        password.hashCode ^
        fname.hashCode ^
        lname.hashCode ^
        expdate.hashCode ^
        tel.hashCode ^
        mobile.hashCode ^
        city.hashCode ^
        address.hashCode ^
        date.hashCode ^
        pish.hashCode ^
        edare.hashCode ^
        flag.hashCode ^
        type.hashCode ^
        img.hashCode;
  }
}
```

**main class**

```
main() {
  ServiseApi().Login_Servise_Api();
}
```

output debug

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:7668/dart_sdk.js:5063:11)
    at Object.castError (http://localhost:7668/dart_sdk.js:5022:15)
    at Object.cast [as as] (http://localhost:7668/dart_sdk.js:5345:17)
    at Function.as_C [as as] (http://localhost:7668/dart_sdk.js:4968:19)
    at Login_Servise_Api (http://localhost:7668/packages/test1/Servis.dart.lib.js:43:87)
    at Login_Servise_Api.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:7668/dart_sdk.js:37788:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:7668/dart_sdk.js:37659:59)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:7668/dart_sdk.js:32861:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:7668/dart_sdk.js:33413:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:7668/dart_sdk.js:33451:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:7668/dart_sdk.js:33299:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:7668/dart_sdk.js:33320:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:7668/dart_sdk.js:37926:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:7668/dart_sdk.js:37932:13)
    at http://localhost:7668/dart_sdk.js:33667:9
Restarted application in ۱۹۱ms.
http://localhost/users.php?key=login&codeMEli=1234567890&pass=12345678
ssssssInstance of 'Response'
number1
[{id: 61, code_office: 72371170, codemeli: 1234567890, password: 12345678, fname: مریم, lname: کریمی, expdate: 1398/11/02, tel: 33679501, mobile: 09177687005, city: بندرعباس, address: گلشهر شمالی کوی نواب نواب 12, date: ۱۳۹۶/۱۰/۱۴, pish: 1, edare: 0, flag: 1, type: 0, img: no_profile_img.jpeg}]
number1-1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your receive `List<Something>` and you Want to Pars `Map<String,SomeThing>`

for Example You receive

```
[
{something}
{something}
]
```

But Your Model Want To Parse

```
{something}
```

---

### Solotion

add this code to your model

```
  static List<Category> fromList(Iterable l) {
    List<Category> data =
        List<Category>.from(l.map((model) => Category.fromJson(model)));
    return data;
  }
```

and use it as below

```
  var data = Category.fromList(json.decode(response.body));
  return data;
```

Comment: code error : The method 'fromJson' isn't defined for the type 'Category'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fromJson'

Comment: your Model is Class is 'ModelUser'  so you should change 'Category' to 'ModelUser'