# Dart: Cannot add _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> to a List<dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart

The body of the response is a JSON like

```
{
  url: https://somename.com,
  id: 12345,
  deviceId: null,
  requiredConsents: []
}
```

Then I decode it and I get `_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>`.

I would like to put that object to a List and displayed it with `ListView.builder` but I get the error:

```
Cannot add _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> to a List<dynamic>
```

Then also the List should be mapped thought the DataModel.

So my question is how can I add the object to the List?

Comment: please try this way ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68465738/problem-in-the-rest-api-flutter-by-package-http/68465876#68465876

Answer (score 0):

Try to do

```dart
List.from(data['requiredConsents']);
```

Comment: hank you for the suggestion, but I still get ``` type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'```

Comment: Actually, on what operation are you getting this error? Maybe you should try do do `map = Map.from(data)` ( with `data` the json object from your question)

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourModel {
  YourModel({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  });

  String? id;
  String? name;

  factory YourModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => YourModel(
    id: json["_id"],
    name: json["name"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "_id": id,
    "name": name,
  };
}
```

```
  getYourModelList() async {
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.http('googl.com', 'api/path'), headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    });
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.body);
      List responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      setState(() {
        yourModelList = responseJson.map((m) => YourModel.fromJson(m)).toList(); //List<YourModel>? yourModelList=[];
      });
    } else {
      print('Error');
    }
  }
```

```
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: yourModelList!.length;,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemBuilder: (context, indexNew) {
                    return Text(yourModelList![index].name);
                  },
                ),
```