# Not able to build custom widget in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to render posts of a created user on profile page. The posts are stored in firestore. Having made a post widget in post.dart along with the post model. The post widget is not building.

The profile.dart has the following code for generating posts.

```
   class Profile extends StatefulWidget {
     final String profileId;
   
     Profile({this.profileId});
   
     @override
     _ProfileState createState() => _ProfileState();
   }
   
   class _ProfileState extends State<Profile> {
     bool isLoading = false;
     int postCount = 0;
     List<Post> posts = [];
     final String currentUserId = currentUser?.id;
   
     @override
     void initState() {
       super.initState();
       getProfilePosts();
     }
     getProfilePosts() async {
       setState(() {
         isLoading=true;
       });
       QuerySnapshot snapshot= await userPostRef
         .document(widget.profileId)
         .collection('userPosts')
         .getDocuments();
   
       setState(() {
         isLoading=false;
         postCount=snapshot.documents.length;
         posts=snapshot.documents.map((doc) =>Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
       });    
     }
   buildProfilePosts(){
       if(isLoading){
         return circularProgress();
       }
       return Column(children:posts);
    
     }
   
     @override
     Widget build(context) {
       return Scaffold(
         appBar: header(context, titleText: "Profile"),
         body: ListView(children: <Widget>[
           buildProfileHeader(),
           Divider(
             height: 0.0,
           ),
           buildProfilePosts(),
         ]),
       );
     }
   }
```

Below is the post.dart file having post model and post widget

```
    class Post extends StatefulWidget {
      final String bucketId;
      final String postId;
      final String userId;
      final String username;
      final String post;
      final dynamic likes;
      final dynamic contributers;
      final String photoUrl;
    
      Post({
        this.bucketId,
        this.postId,
        this.userId,
        this.username,
        this.post,
        this.likes,
        this.contributers,
        this.photoUrl,
      });
    
      factory Post.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
        return Post(
          postId: doc['postId'],
          userId: doc['userId'],
          bucketId: doc['bucketId'],
          username: doc['username'],
          post: doc['post'],
          contributers: doc['contributers'],
          likes: doc['likes'],
          photoUrl: doc['photoUrl'],
        );
      }
    
      
     @override
      _PostState createState() => _PostState(
            postId: this.postId,
            bucketId: this.bucketId,
            userId: this.userId,
            username: this.username,
            post: this.post,
            likes: this.likes,
            contributers: this.contributers,
            likeCount: getLikeCount(this.likes),
            photoUrl: this.photoUrl,
          );
    }
    
    class _PostState extends State<Post> {
      final String currentUserId=currentUser?.id;
      final String bucketId;
      final String postId;
      final String userId;
      final String username;
      final String post;
      final String photoUrl;
      Map likes;
      Map contributers;
      int likeCount;
    
      _PostState({
        this.bucketId,
        this.postId,
        this.userId,
        this.username,
        this.post,
        this.likes,
        this.contributers,
        this.likeCount,
        this.photoUrl,
      });
    
      buildPostHeader(){
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: usersRef.document(userId).get(),
          builder: (context,snapshot){
            if(!snapshot.hasData){
              return circularProgress();
            }
            User user=User.fromDocument(snapshot.data);
            bool isPostOwner = currentUserId==userId;
            return ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(user.photoUrl),
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              ),
              title: GestureDetector(
                onTap: ()=> print('showing profile'),
                child: Text(
                  user.displayName,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(
                  "@"+user.username,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal
                  ),
               ),
               trailing: isPostOwner ? IconButton(
                 onPressed: ()=>handleDeletePost(context),
                 icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
               ):Text(''),
               
               );
          }
        
        );
      }
    
     
      buildPostBody(){
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: ()=>print('go to bucket'),
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Card(
                child: Text(
                  post,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    
      buildPostFooter(){
        return Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, left: 20.0)),
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    GestureDetector (
                      onTap: () => print('liking post'),
                      child: Icon(
                                Icons.favorite_border,
                                size: 28.0,
                                color: Colors.pink,
                              ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      likeCount.toString(),
                    ),
    
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0)),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => print('showing comments'),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.chat,
                    size: 28.0,
                    color: Colors.blue[900],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
        );
      }
      
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                print("Building widget");
        return Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
             buildPostHeader(),
    
              buildPostBody(),
              buildPostFooter(),
          ],
    
        );
      }
    }
```

The debug console shows the following error

```
    Restarted application in 1,647ms.
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    The following _TypeError was thrown building NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification>:
    type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'
    
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    ListView
    When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
    #0      Post.createState
    #1      new StatefulElement
    #2      StatefulWidget.createElement
    #3      Element.inflateWidget
    #4      MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget
    ...
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 258 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    ListView
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    A RenderSliverPadding expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderErrorBox.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    ListView
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    ListView
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    ListView
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    ListView
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    ListView
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    ListView
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    ListView
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    Scaffold
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    Scaffold
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    Scaffold
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    Scaffold
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    Scaffold
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    Scaffold
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    Scaffold
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    Scaffold
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    Scaffold
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    Scaffold
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    Scaffold
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    Profile
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    
    ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
    'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4269 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
    The relevant error-causing widget was
    Profile
    ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: FWIW relying on type inference often results in more cryptic error messages. I don't know if it would help here, but type dynamic can mean a type can't be reliably inferred.  You could try adding return types for your functions and see if you get a more clear error message. i.e. `Widget  buildPostFooter(){...}`

Comment: Added return Widget to functions, but it is still showing the same errors.

Comment: Both `Map likes` and `Map contributers` are Map<dynamic,dynamic> (since there's no type in the declaration). Have you checked that  `DocumentSnapshot['contributers']` and `DocumentSnapshot['likes']` are Maps (and not Lists)?

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Please look at this answer . https://stackoverflow.com/a/68465876/6813907

Comment: Hey @AyushSaxena any updates... try and check my answer it most probably will work for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is way too much going on. Please strip your example. I am unable to copy and execute the code because dependencies are missing (like the `User` class).

The code is very messy, you're mixing view logic, application logic, models, and view models everywhere which makes it hard to grasp, where and why the exception arises. Also, you work with `Map`s because the Firestore returns these kinds of data types. Instead you should convert the dynamic `Map`s to your own (view)model classes. This way, the compiler could give a much better explanation about what's wrong.

It has probably something to do with the properties you have declared as `dynamic` ("likes" and "contributers"). Have you tried to debug whether they are really `Map`s and not `List`s? Because in the `Post` constructor you declare them as `dynamic` whereas in the `PostState` you expect `Map`s.

Can you at least narrow the issue down to a Widget? Does the problem persist when you don't render the header and footer?

Answer (score 1):

profile.dart

```
getProfilePosts() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading=true;
    });
    QuerySnapshot snapshot= await userPostRef
      .document(widget.profileId)
      .collection('userPosts')
      .getDocuments();

    setState(() {
      isLoading=false;
      postCount=snapshot.documents.length;
      posts=snapshot.documents.map((doc){
          Post.fromDocument(doc)
      }).toList();
    });    
}
```

In `post.dart` change factory method to this

```
factory Post.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot document) {
         Map<String, dynamic> doc = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
        return Post(
          postId: doc['postId'],
          userId: doc['userId'],
          bucketId: doc['bucketId'],
          username: doc['username'],
          post: doc['post'],
          contributers: doc['contributers'],
          likes: doc['likes'],
          photoUrl: doc['photoUrl'],
        );
      }
```

**Try this**

Comment: Do you mean doc.data by value.data()?

Comment: Also Post.fromDocument is expecting a DocumentSnapshot as argument

Comment: Yeah, that's doc Sorry my bad. Ok, I'll check and update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try these changes,

**change your code from**,

```
posts=snapshot.documents.map((doc) =>Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList()
```

**to**,

```
posts=snapshot.documents.map((doc) =>Post.fromDocument(doc))
```

As firestore already returns list of objects for your request and you are again converting that to list so it might be the possible error cause. So **removing your `.toList()` method should solve the error**.

first run with the above changes if that didnt worked out then go ahead with below changes too,

then try removing your `posts` and `postCount` in `setState` it should be outside of setState method and run your project it might solve the error

and also you should use `async` and `await` in your code for getting the data from firestore otherwise your data which is fetched will be incomplete

for more info on QuerySnapshot refer this:

[what does QuerySnapshot returns](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot#:%7E:text=DocumentChange%3E%20getDocumentChanges%20()-,Returns%20the%20list%20of%20documents%20that%20changed%20since%20the%20last,the%20list%20as%20added%20changes.)
Returns the list of documents that changed since the last snapshot. If it's the first snapshot all documents will be in the list as added changes